# Spring boot 2.7 'dependencies.dependency.version' for com.mysql:mysql-connector-j:jar

Tags: spring-boot-starter

I am upgrading Java 8 to Java 17

Spring Batch 2.3.3 to 2.7

here are the changes [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xpcTN.png)

I got the error with my-sql connector ..

changed it to [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cd7uN.png)

Reloaded maven dependencies .. when I run I still get
'dependencies.dependency.version' for com.mysql:mysql-connector-j:jar is missing.

how do I fix this?

(https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cd7uN.png)

Comment: You need to post the code and error messages in text form to the question, image questions are not allowed and will likely cause others to vote down the question's ranking leading to it to be auto-closed and hurt your reputation/ability  to post new questions.  So I highly suggest you update it.

Comment: You may want to read [ask]

Comment: The title and the texts succinctly summarize everything I needed to convey or inquire about. The pictures just serve as supportive evidence for any suggested changes. Kindly refrain from voting down if you don't fully understand the context of the question .

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
```

adding the runtime  tag along the spring-batch depencies got it fixed.